# 429 Client Error: TooManyRequests for url

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have a script that executes an ingestion statement with a certain period. In simplified way it looks as follows:

```py
import time
from azure.kusto.data import KustoClient, KustoConnectionStringBuilder, ClientRequestProperties


cluster = "https://<adxname>.centralus.kusto.windows.net"
client_id = "<sp_guid>"
client_secret = "<sp_secret>"
authority_id = "<tenant_guid>"
db = "db-name"

kcsb = KustoConnectionStringBuilder.with_aad_application_key_authentication(
    cluster, client_id, client_secret, authority_id)
client = KustoClient(kcsb)

query = """
.append my_table <|
another_table | where ... | summarize ... | project ...
"""

while True:
    client.execute(db, query)
    time.sleep(30.0)
```

So it executes a small query every 30 seconds. The query takes only milliseconds to complete. Lib version: `azure-kusto-data==3.1.0`.

It works fine for a while, but after some time it starts failing with this error:

> requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 429 Client Error: TooManyRequests for
> url:
> https://adxname.centralus.kusto.windows.net/v1/rest/mgmt
>
> azure.kusto.data.exceptions.KustoApiError: The control command was
> aborted due to throttling. Retrying after some backoff might succeed.
> CommandType: 'TableAppend', Capacity: 1, Origin:
> 'CapacityPolicy/Ingestion'.

Looking at the CapacityPolicy/Ingestion mentioned in the error, I cannot see how it can be relevant. This policy left as default:

```
.show cluster policy capacity

"Policy": {
  "IngestionCapacity": {
    "ClusterMaximumConcurrentOperations": 512,
    "CoreUtilizationCoefficient": 0.75
  },
  ...
}
```

I do not quite understand how it can be related to concurrent operations or core utilization as ingestion is fast and rarely executed.

How to troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message, the ingestion capacity for your cluster is 1. This likely indicates you're using the dev SKU that has a single node with 2 cores.

With such a setup, only a single ingestion operation can run at a given time. Any additional concurrent ingestions will be throttled.

You can either implement tighter control over the client(s) ingesting into the cluster, so that no more than a single ingestion command attempts to run concurrently, and the calling code can recover from throttling errors; or scale the cluster up/out - by adding more nodes/cores you'll be increasing the ingestion capacity.

You can also verify who/what else is ingesting into your cluster by using `.show commands`

Comment: The only other ingestion is streaming from an Event Hub, which is unpredictable. It looks like client retrying is the only option for dev SKU...

Comment: you can also alter the capacity policy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/capacitypolicy

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have a monitoring or admin permission on the database you can run the following to see the ingestion activity for any given time period (ensure that you have all types in the "in" clause), for example:

```
.show commands 
| where StartedOn > ago(1h)
| where CommandType in ("DataIngestPull", "TableAppend", "TableSetOrReplace", "TableSetOrAppend")
| summarize count() by CommandType
```

As a side note, for this type of operation, you should consider using [materialized views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-overview).

Comment: I need to log some historical state, say max() on a certain timestamp, and later query it. Could you please describe how can mat views help in this case?

Comment: not the scope for this question . read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-create).
Basically it will constantly aggregate the result for you so when you query it will return faster.